# How do I create a toolbar in an XLA document?

Tags: excel, commandbar, xla, vba

How do I create a toolbar for Excel using an XLA document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a toolbar, in the onload event, you are going to do something like:

```
Dim myBar As CommandBar, myButt As CommandBarControl 

'Delete the toolbar if it already exists'
On Error Resume Next 
CommandBars("My Toolbar").Delete 
On Error Goto 0

Set myBar = CommandBars.Add(Name:="My Toolbar", _
      Position:=msoBarFloating, Temporary:=True) 
myBar.Visible = True 

 ' Create a button with text on the bar and set some properties.'
Set myButt = ComBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton) 
With myButt
    .Caption = "Macro1" 
    .Style = msoButtonCaption 
    .TooltipText = "Run Macro1" 
    .OnAction = "Macro1" 
End With 

 ' Create a button with an image on the bar and set some properties.'
Set myButt = ComBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton) 
With myButt  
     'the faceId line will let you choose an icon'
     ' If you choose to use the faceId then the caption is not displayed'
    .FaceId = 1000 
    .Caption = "Icon Button" 
    .TooltipText = "Run Macro2" 
    .OnAction = "Macro2" 
End With
```

The polite thing to do is delete the toolbar on exit, also.

Comment: @BradC--interesting variable name there. :-)

Comment: hehe, myBar, myButt, myAss(embly)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but I thought this might help you out:

[Excel -- Macro Toolbar](http://www.contextures.com/xlToolbar02.html)

Since you don't specify a version of Excel I'm not sure if this will work for you or not but perhaps it will furnish you with a good starting point.